# Capturing Outlook.OlInspectorClose value

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing an Outlook 2010 add-in that needs to perform different tasks depending on whether a message is going to be saved as a draft or discarded.  I know that the value of **Outlook.OlInspectorClose** can be set programatically, but I'm unable to determine how to capture this variable when the user closes the inspector window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`InspectorEvents_10_CloseEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorevents_10_closeeventhandler.aspx) does not have any event arguments - so the [SaveOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208102%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is not available. You could try checking the inspector [`Saved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.saved.aspx) flag to see if there are any pending changes that were not saved. You could tell if a new item was saved if it has an [EntryID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb207146%28v=office.12%29.aspx) assigned.

Comment: I don't see how to access that yet, but I"m going to give this link a try:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg583879.aspx

Comment: that didn't do what I had hoped.  still searching.

Comment: saw the "saved" flag on Outlook.MailItem, but it's not reporting correctly on close when I choose to save or discard